# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'image' (T_STRING) in eval line

Tags: eval, exiftool, php-parse-error

I`m trying to create a page that read the metadata of an image and allow user to edit it and save it to the same image.

After searching the internet I have found exiftool as the solution but I can make it work only as a command line not as a library in the page.

I have this code:

`eval('$metadata=' . exiftool.exe -php -q $imagePath);
foreach ($metadata[0] as $key => $value) {
     if ($metadata[0][$key]!=$_POST[$key]){
    if ($_POST[$key]=="") $_POST[$key]=" "; //if metadata is not set, than create an empty metadata
        eval('$metadata=' . exiftool.exe "-$key=$_POST[$key]" $imagePath);
    }
     }`

and I`m getting this error:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'image' (T_STRING) in E:\xampp\htdocs\imgdata\index.php(30) : eval()'d code on line 1

I tried to replace the ` with other like " and ' but no luck.
What do I miss?
Any better idea on how to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but using Centos OS, and found a solution here:

['command not found' error when using subprocess in apache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8544953/command-not-found-error-when-using-subprocess-in-apache/8549087#8549087)

Might not work for Windows but worth a look. Basically the answer suggests specifying the full exiftool path rather than simply exiftool.exe.

If that doesn't help then have a look for errors in the Apache Error Log File.